# Deserialize only specific item from XML and add to list

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I've got an XML file with multiple items, and I want to deserialize only a single specific one at a time, rather than all of them, and add it to a list.

Using the example from [this site](http://www.janholinka.net/Blog/Article/11), how do I deserialize only the `Product` where `Id=2` and add it to `productList`?

The Class:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Code:

```
void foo()
{
string xmlString = "<Products><Product><Id>1</Id><Name>My XML product</Name></Product><Product><Id>2</Id><Name>My second product</Name></Product></Products>";

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Product>), new XmlRootAttribute("Products"));

StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlString);

List<Product> productList = (List<Product>)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
}
```

Comment: Why not use LINQ to XML or some other XML parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the XDocument class to query Xml:

```
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlString);
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(stringReader);

var node = document.Descendants("Product").FirstOrDefault(p => p.Descendants("Id").First().Value == "2");
if(node != null)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Product));
    var xmlReader = new StringReader(node.ToString());
    Product result = serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader) as Product;
}
```

Granted, this is a quick and dirty solution that may require further analysis for certain situations.

Answer (score 1):

Here this is working, you should Create `XmlReader` with your StringReader and read the subtree of the element. This can be achieved with `ReadSubtree` method.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xmlString = "<Products><Product><Id>1</Id><Name>My XML product</Name></Product><Product><Id>2</Id><Name>My second product</Name></Product></Products>";

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Product>), new XmlRootAttribute("Products"));
        List<Product> productList = new List<Product>();

        using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlString))
        using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader))
        {
            xmlReader.ReadToDescendant("Products");
            productList = (List<Product>)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader.ReadSubtree());
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but that code deserializes both items, like the code in my example, not just the one where `Id=2`.